# Set default light and dark themes

Tags: neovim, colorscheme

How can I set the default `colorscheme` according the current shell light/dark theme?

I thought about using an if..else statement reading the background variable, but on my light theme terminals, background is "dark" during loading and "light" afterwards.

None of my config files set a value on background, but according `:verbose set background?` last value was set on Lua (no file path given)

Comment: According to theme of what? The "background" is yet another user-changeable option in vim.

Comment: according the shell theme. At least in Mac and Linux whenever I set a light/dark theme I can see the background value inheriting the value from the shell theme. If I have two shells, one with dark and another one with light theme, I can see vim using a different light/dark theme too automatically.

Comment: AFAIR, neovim always sets "dark" by default. So you need to read any external os/app settings yourself. Needless to say, linux/macos/1001 various shells all can have very different apis.

Comment: In my case, neovim is inheriting from the shell the right color theme. In my boot scripts it is always "dark" but once the editor is loaded, the same `background` value is set to "light" only if it was started from a shell with light theme

Comment: If the whole problem is about the execution order then postpone your code until some event, such as VimEnter, UIEnter or such.